# Like Button broken on URL "http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=APP_ID"

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, lint

Like button (iframe / like.php plugin) of our Facebook app is broken for some days.

We have choose to use "http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=APP_ID" url instead of "http://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAME/" format (maybe not a good idea).

A click on it leads to a failure (popup telling "There was an error liking the page. If you are the page owner, please try running your page through the linter on the Facebook devsite (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) and fixing any errors.")

Linter is able to find that http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=APP_ID must be converted to "Final URL : http://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAME/"

Redirect Path section says "Final URL is in bold (this is the URL we tried to extract metadata from)" and final URL is correct (http://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAME)

But in this case, linter is not able to scrap Open Tags included into  "http://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAME" despite the fact that open tags are well recognized if final URL "http://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAME" is directly submitted to linter.

It seems that open graph tags of final url are no more used.

Can someone confirm me that this a new behaviour/bug and tell how to solve it ?
Could I migrate our likes from one url (.../apps/application.php?id=APP_ID)  to a new one that works (.../APP_NAME/) ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Those /apps/application.php URLs were [deprecated in December 2011](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/) and removed in February 2012 - you shouldn't still be using them, they automatically redirect to the app's canvas or website URL. Like buttons may have given some semblance of still working on those URLs for a few months afterwards, but effectively anyone clicking them was becoming a fan of nothing

Your like button or Like Box should be pointing to the Page for your app if you have one.  That blog post has instructions for creating one if you didn't migrate between December 2011 and February 2011

If you don't have a page for your app, there's no purpose to accumulating fans via the Like button as you can't target ads to them or send them updates.

There's instructions for creating a Page in the blog post i linked above, or in the [Communicating with your users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/Communicating_With_Users/) doc.

Comment: Many thanks for the information. We had already built a "Page for app" and like button on it is working fine now. However, its url has following format : "http://www.facebook.com/pages/APP_NAME/3012970632617..". Is there any way to obtain a user-friendly URL ? (ie "http://www.facebook.com/APP_NAME)" Thanks again

Comment: No, that would, if in place, send users to the canvas app, which you don't have

Comment: Well I was talking about this kind of url behind like button : "//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=**http://www.facebook.com/pioneertrail**.   www.facebook.com/pioneertrail is userfriendly and is an app page.

Comment: That's different, that's a regular app page which was either linked with the app during the migration period or created afterwards - the application.php pages aren't likeable